# No recognizer of the required ID found.\r\nParameter name: culture

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I am developing Speech Recognizing program using microsoft speech recognizer[Microsoft.Speech.Recognition]

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new   CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToString())); //exception occurred here 
 // Create a simple grammar that recognizes “red”, “green”, or “blue”.
        Choices colors = new Choices();
        colors.Add("red");
        colors.Add("green");
        colors.Add("blue");

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(colors);

        // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        //string str;
        ////RecognizerInfo rf = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers();
        //SpeechRecognitionEngine spe = new SpeechRecognitionEngine ();
        //str = spe.RecognizerInfo.Id;
        //string cul = spe.RecognizerInfo.Culture.NativeName ;
    }

    // Simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
    void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
    }
}
```

copy paste from accepted answer 
when i run this program i got exception while reinitialize object "sre"

Additional information: No recognizer of the required ID found.

Exception- {"No recognizer of the required ID found.\r\nParameter name: culture"}

```
at Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine..ctor(CultureInfo culture)
at Text_To_Speech.SpeechToText.SpeechToText_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\VSTest\ProjeTest\form\Text To Speech\Text To Speech\Text To Speech\SpeechToText.cs:line 41
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Dev environment

windows server 2012 X86

visual studio 2015

MicrosoftSpeechPlatformSDK - version 11.0 X86

SpeechPlatformRuntime

Comment: It is very uncommon that you can use a recognizer for a language that is not the same as the language version of your operating system.  It requires installing the language-specific support, it is hard to come by since Microsoft supports just a few languages.  Certainly not one of the Indic languages.

Comment: @HansPassant current culture return en-US &  text to speech running fine